# Add and replace fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I found funny things with fragments. I created activity and added two fragments:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.main, new Fragment1());
ft.add(R.id.main, new Fragment2());
ft.commit();
```

Then I added button with code:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.main, new Fragment1());
ft.commit();
```

If I press first time - Fragment1 is destroying, if I press second time - Fragment2 is destroying. Why is it work so? I think that if I'm replacing fragments then container 'main' should be cleaned.

Answer (score 1):

To start, I wouldn't add two fragments to the same container. If you want to use the same container, my recommendation would be to use 2 containers both within a third container

If you *need* to add two fragments to the same container, you can manually get rid of them by keeping their objects around (or referencing them in some way).

For example this uses the fully qualified `FragmentTransaction.add()` in order to later reference the fragments

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.main, new Fragment1(), "frag1");
ft.add(R.id.main, new Fragment2(), "frag2");
ft.commit();

// Later on
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
// Manually remove fragments
ft.remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag1"));
ft.remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag2"));
ft.add(R.id.main, new Fragment1(), "newFrag1");
ft.commit();
```

From my understanding, the problem with relying on replace to get rid of multiple fragments inside the same container is that it will replace which ever is "currently showing" not the entire container (although, reading the [documentation on FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)  - it certainly makes it sound like you should be able to do exactly what you are doing).

Comment: Why wouldn't you use one container? Just replace everytime you want to add a container. That's how Google samples are doing it and that's how it supposed to be done. Having different containers for every fragment defies the purpose of having containers.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29)

"This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here."

Answer (score 0):

Try to use addToBackStack(null) after the replace:

```
ft.replace(R.id.main, new Fragment1());
ft.addToBackStack(null)
ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose fragment f1 and f2
if u replace f2 fragment on f1  then 
f1  fragment 
onpause
ondestroyview
ondestroy
ondetach

and f2
oncreate
oncreateview
onactivitycreated
onstart
onresume

called

if u add f2 on f1
then 
f1
onpause
and f2
oncreate
oncreateview
onactivitycreated
onstart
onresume

are called